# How to partially updates a knockout obervableArray?

Tags: listview, knockout.js

I have a large list of objects as infinite scroll, along with a "select all" function.

When the list grows beyond the size of 1000 objects, browser simply hangs on selection update.

I want to make it only update items within the current view port.

How should I do it?

EDIT:

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/vicary/8Yw4F/) does not produce a lot of DOM redraw, not the best way to show the latency. But you get the idea. When I update the `selectAll` observable, browser will stop working for some time.

Comment: please provide some sample code with what you have tried.

Comment: Use paging instead of loading all items at a time.

Comment: Voter please explain how I violate community standards so I can ask questions in better quality in the future.

Comment: I'd probably suggest 'unloading' (removing from the DOM) earlier items when you have scrolled a bit. Working with a DOM with so many items is generally not a good idea. On the other hand, the user probably don't see the top ones any more (unless the user has a really high screen resolution), so you're probably fine unloading items higher up (just re-add them if the user scrolls back up). A very bad workaround would be setting the selection value in batches, letting the browser update in between. The real solution is not having that amount of object loaded into the DOM, however your do it.